# OnClick Java Script - reload child records

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a detail page button that is currently calling an APEX class. After the class has executed I am reloading the page that the button was clicked on. Is there anyway to also reload related lists/child records off the parent?

At the moment I have:`window.location.reload();`
but is there any form of `window.location.child.reload();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Classic, there's no way to reload the related lists without reloading the entire page. In Lightning, you can use [force:refreshView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm) to cause the data to be refreshed from the server without an entire page load. This is part of the magic that makes Lightning far faster than Classic. Unfortunately, Classic users can't enjoy this behavior, so window.location.reload() is the best you can do until you decide to migrate to Lightning Experience.

Answer (score 0):

Related lists on the parent object page are updated when the page reloads.  Are you performing child object record DML operations asynchronously?  Are you refreshing the page prior to the transaction being completed?  If so you may want to create a callback or return a promise to time the refresh accordingly.